# How can I create a MxNx2 array of row, col indices?

Tags: numpy

I would like to make an array of the indices of a 2D matrix MxNx2, something like this for M=N=2:

```
[[[0,0], [0,1]],

 [[1,0], [1,1]]]
```

Is there an easy way to do this in Numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`np.indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) -

```
np.indices((M,N)).transpose(1,2,0)
```

Alternative to transposing axes -

```
np.moveaxis(np.indices((M,N)),0,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a direct method which results in a contiguous array:

```
M,N = 3,4
MM,NN,DD = np.ogrid[:M,:N,:2]
MM*(1-DD)+NN*DD
```

Result:

```
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 2],
        [0, 3]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 3]],

       [[2, 0],
        [2, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [2, 3]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make use of [**`np.meshgrid`** [numpy-doc]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) here:

```
np.transpose(np.meshgrid(np.arange(m), np.arange(n)))
```

For example for `m = 3` and `n = 4`:

```
>>> np.transpose(np.meshgrid(np.arange(m), np.arange(n)))
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 2],
        [0, 3]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 3]],

       [[2, 0],
        [2, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [2, 3]]])
```